# How do I add multiple non-exclusive probabilities

Tags: statistics

What I've learned about adding probabilities is that mutually exclusive probabilities you can just add together: $P(A \ or \ B)=P(A)+P(B)$. If they are non-mutually exclusive the probability $A$ or $B$ will occur is: $P(A \ or \ B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \ and \ B)$ where the last term is the overlap of the two events. When it comes to dealing with two probabilities I've been able to solve, but I have a problem where I have 5 different probabilities that an a certain amount of cars will go through an intersection within the time span of 5 minutes. The following table has the probabilities I am working with:

[image]

I need to find out the probability at least one car will pass in the time span. I thought the way to do this would be to add up the probabilities from 1 cars to 5, then subtract them from one another due to the overlap of the events because these are non-mutually exclusive.
$$(0.28+0.15+0.10+0.07+0.04)-(0.28-0.15-0.10-0.07-0.04)=0.72$$
This looked OK to me because the number is less than $1$, which it must be less than, but apparently this isn't the right answer.

What is the right way to add more than two probabilities together?

Comment: Worth knowing $P(A \text{ or } B) = 1 - P(\text { not } A \text{ and not } B).$  At least one car will pass is the complement to no cars will pass.

Comment: I think that they are mutually exclusive. The count of cars for a given 5 minutes has to be a single number - you can have either 2 or 3 but not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count all the probabilities from your table, they will add up to 1.

The event that (exactly) 5 cars pass through the intersection in a span of 5 minutes, **cannot overlap**  the event that (exactly) 1 car pass through the intersection in the **same span** of 5 minutes.

**Illustration :**

This may help you understand, these probabilities could arise from a research with 1000 data. Each data is a number of total cars that pass through intersection at **different** span of 5 minutes. Probability only 1 car that pass through, is the ratio of the total number of data of 1 car pass through the intersection, 280, and the total number of data, 1000. Overall, the each proportion makes up your probability table. **These events are mutually exclusive.**

> The probability of at least one car pass through the intersection can
>   be counted in these ways, with $C=c$ as the event of total of $c$ cars
>   pass through intersection in a span of 5 minutes :
>
> 1. $$ P(C>0)= \sum_{i=1}^{5} P(C=i) $$
> 2. $$ P(C>0)= 1 - P(C=0) $$

---

An example where two events are not mutually exclusive are $C>1$ and $C>2$. (Recall the illustration above) This is because all the data that satisfy $C>2$ will also satisfy $C>1$, so there are overlaps.

Comment: Oh! That does make sense. One question that goes along with that data asked what the probability between 2 and 4 cars (inclusive) pass through the intersection. Now I'm assuming that just meant that you also include the probabilities for 2 and 4.

Comment: Probability between 2 and 4 cars (exclusive) means $P(2 < C < 4)=P(C=3)$. Probability between 2 and 4 cars (inclusive) means $P(2 \le C \le 4) $.